# Search and replace with parameters

Tags: search, replace, emacs

I have a long YAML config file which I'd like to change. 
I would like to replace an attribute "url" with as dictionaries of url, for instance change,

```
url: https://bla.bla
```

into

```
url: {my_key: https://bla.bla}
```

So basically, for a given string "s" which is found after `url` key, I'd like to wrap it around `{key: s}`

Is there an efficient way to do this using basic text editor find and replace features? I am using spacemacs by the way

Comment: Are there any other keys that need inserting? If not what determines that you do `{my_key: some_url}` instead of `{key: some_other_url}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can run: <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp`, which for me is mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd> in "regular" emacs.

When prompted for a regexp you can try:

`.*url:[ ]*\(.*\)`

or the slightly more rigorous option that will remove leading and trailing spaces:

`^.*url:[ ]*\([^ ]+\)[ ]*$`

and hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

When prompted for replacement text, try:

`{ my_key: \1 }`

If the pattern matches, you just hit <kbd>y</kbd> to confirm, or <kbd>!</kbd> to auto-confirm the rest. Backup your data first.  In the regular expression, the pattern between parentheses gets "captured" (there can be multiple captures).  In the replacement, the \1 is replaced with the first captured pattern.  Invest some time in learning regular expressions. They are very powerful.

Comment: `[ ]` is an odd way to represent a space; and your greedy "anything" group will guarantee that the following zero-or-more spaces will in fact be zero spaces, so that's clearly not what you intended. (FYI `*?` and `+?` are non-greedy variants of `*` and `+`). You're dropping the `url: ` from the text, as well.

Comment: it was what I intended.  it was meant to consume any white space at the end of the line so it was not captured.  I spent around a minute on the answer,  feel free to improve it.

Comment: Any white space at the end of the line was already captured in the greedy `\(.*\)`.  I highly recommend that you experiment with the non-greedy operators to understand how those work.  e.g. consider `\(.*?\) *$`